# Encryption and Decryption to Create a 16 character alphanumeric string only using c#

Tags: encryption

Is there any way to encrypt the whole Input data into 16 to 24 character alphanumeric string and again able to decrypt it into normal string in c#?

Comment: This question is really off-topic for StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I would recommend you read a bit about [Information Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory).

Comment: If you found the answer useful please consider marking the answer as correct (the green tick on the left).

Answer (score 0):

It depends but the general answer is: no, there is no way to encrypt a string of arbitrary length to a constant length and be able to decode it.